# Random Number generator function ran2 Numerical Recipes

Tags: math, random, generator, simulation

Given that we start the call to the function ran2 with a negative integer [the seed] it will produce a series of random numbers. The sequence can be regenerated exactly if the same seed is used.

Now my question is that is there a way that we can directly enter into some point in the sequence and then continue from that point onwards ? For example if the random numbers for a certain seed are 0.35, 0.32, 0.44,0.32,0.66,0.32, 0.45.

If we know that seed which gave rise to this sequence, is there a way to get the function to return 0.66 and then continue from that point onwards?

The way I want to use it is in a simulation. Whereby if my simulation ends at a certain point and I need to restart it I should continue with the same sequence of random numbers.
Thanks.

Comment: Why not maintain an stack of simulation states (the particular random number being just another piece of information) so that it is easier for you to backtrack/resume/pause/replay?

Comment: @Igancio.
From the book Numerical Recipes: The Art of Scientific Computing. 
http://www.nr.com/ 
Fortran version. But I guess it shouldn't matter which language the program is in.

Comment: @dirkgently: That would involve saving too much output. I'm talking about tens of millions of calls to the function. So it would be great to have a direct way of reaching some point in the series provided we know the seed.

Comment: Serialize the output when you cross a certain limit. Keep in memory only a certain number of states (locality of context) which is good enough for backtracking and load the earlier states on demand. Otherwise,

Answer (score 2):

I'd agree with @dirkgently's comment above. While I'm not familiar with `ran2` specifically, based on [this sample code](http://www.physics.upenn.edu/~garyb/Astro503/ran2.c) it looks like there are a handful of stateful pieces (`idum`, `idum2`, `iy` and `iv`) that could be encapsulated out and stored. When you 'pause' your simulation you can save off this state and write it back into the `ran2` engine the next time you start things up. Restoring the state information should put the machine right back where it left off, and the random sequence can resume. This may require a little modification of the `ran2` code itself, but should not be a difficult change to fold in.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  You'll have to save and restore everything that's declared `static` (which means moving them out to be file globals and adding save/restore functions) but that will permit you to pick up the sequence where it left off.